# How to Fan-Out SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have multiple sources which are pushing raw data to S3. I have configured a SQS event notification over my S3 bucket.
The problem is the lag and limitations.

I anticipate that there will be more sources in near future and since we can get only 10 messages in a single poll from SQS, I think that in the near future when there will be more sources that will push data to S3, then the SQS will be full of some thousands of messages and I won't be able to process them faster.

I am thinking to fan-out SQS by spreading the message to more SQS queues from my master SQS queue, so that my processing layer can poll multiple queues eg: 5 queues and process more messages.
What should be the probable approach?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> *"... since we can get only 10 Messages in a single poll from SQS...I am thinking to fan-out sqs like spreading the message to more SQS queues from my master SQS queue, so that my processing layer can poll multiple queues eg : 5 queues and process more messages."*

Short Answer: **Don't do this.**

**Here's why:**

Yes, a single poll can retrieve up to 10 messages. However, you can have **multiple threads and multiple hosts all polling a single queue**.  Getting your consumers to run in parallel is the key here, as processing queue entries will be your bottleneck - not retrieving entries from the queue. A single SQS queue can handle tons of polling threads.

A multi-queue fanout as you proposed would have a number of drawbacks:

1. More complicated to code & operate
2. Slower - items will have to go through the overhead of transfer from your main queue (or SNS if you use that) to the consumption queues
3. More expensive - SQS charges per message. SNS charges per message.
4. You'll have to deal with duplication on your own - with a single queue, SQS built-in visibility timeout will mostly prevent other consumers from working on the same items. With multiple queues, you'll have to come up with a deduplication strategy of your own
5. Just use a single queue. You'll thank me later.

Answer (score 8):

The typical way to fanout messages to multiple sqs queues is to use SNS.

The s3 event notifications would goto SNS instead of SQS and the SNS would be responsible for fanning those messages out to as many queues as you want.

That said, I am not sure I understand why you think you will be able to process messages faster if you use multiple message queues.

A single queue SQS queue being polled by either multiple processing clients or a single client using multi-threading are probably both better ways to improve processing speed than simply introducing more queues.